# How do I ignore a part of the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current rewrite rules looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/video/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /video/index.php [L]
```

URL's like `example.com/video/?p=2231&c=395840&s=849264&l=101641` works fine.

For SEO reasons, I need to allow any string between `video/` and `?p=2231&c=395840&s=849264&l=101641`. For example, the URL `example.com/video/string/string/?p=2231&c=395840&s=849264&l=101641` should not map `/string/string/` to index.php.

I tried the following rule, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^video/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /video/$3 [L]
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need Query String parameters, you can try this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^video(.*) /video/index.php [QSA,L]
```

QSA Flag will "forward" parameters to next script (ie index.php).

Comment: Well not only, coz video should be forward to index.php to. So if i type /video/string/string/?p=id index.php should get /video/?p=id without /string/string/.

Comment: This rewrite will do that. But, user will still see first URL. If you need to explicitely redirect the user, change RR flags to [QSA,L,R=301]